# Correct typing of a method without a fixed signature

Tags: python, python-typing

I wonder what is the correct way to type hint [`scrapy.Spider.parse()`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/2.11.0/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py#L81).

If defined in a subclass, it has a specific first argument (`response: Response`) but can have an arbitrary list of additional arguments (including an empty one), with or without `**kwargs`. As a best approximation for this, it's currently defined in the base class with a `self, response: Response, **kwargs: Any` signature, but overriding it with a different one causes mypy errors.

Changing the signature is fine from the API perspective because the correct signature in specific user code depends on other parts of the user code. If `SpiderA` and `SpiderB` inherit from `scrapy.Spider`, it usually makes sense to expect compatible signatures between `SpiderA` and its descendants but not between any two in `SpiderA`, `SpiderB` and `scrapy.Spider`. But declaring `scrapy.Spider.parse()` as an abstract method and `scrapy.Spider` as an ABC doesn't make sense as its descendants aren't required to define `parse()` at all (as they don't always use that method).

So I wonder if there is an accepted way to tell the tools that child classes can have somewhat different signatures in this method if they override it at all, or in the worst case mark the parent class code in a way that doesn't produce typing errors in descendant user code (I guess removing type hints will achieve this but this is the very last resort: while it can be argued that type hints for this method aren't very useful it feels strange to omit them from one method while striving to type hint all other code).

Comment: It's usually wrong for subclasses to have a different signature. If there are optional arguments, they should all use `*args, **kwargs`.

Comment: @Barmar well yeah but I tried to explain why this is fine from the code perspective in these cases. I understand that if everything was simple the type hints would also be simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what type-checker you're using, but there was a PR in [mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/14656) and [pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/5715) to make this possible recently, by supporting `Ellipsis` (`...`) as the last argument to [`typing.Concatenate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Concatenate), so you can specify `Response` as the type of the first argument, then use `...` to not care about the type of the remaining arguments. I expect the next version of mypy and pylance to support this.

The following can be checked on [mypy-playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict&gist=c1cfc8347e38549d78dda4780d81a752), running on the mypy master branch:

```py
import typing_extensions as t
if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import collections.abc as cx

class Response: ...

class Spider:
    if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
        parse: cx.Callable[t.Concatenate[Response, ...], t.Any]
    else:
        def parse(self, response: Response, **kwargs: t.Any) -> t.Any:
            raise NotImplementedError(f"{self.__class__.__name__}.parse callback is not defined")


class GoodSpider(Spider):
    def parse(self, response: Response, *, a: int) -> None: ...  # OK

class BadSpider1(Spider):
    def parse(self, response: str) -> None: ...  # Error
    
class BadSpider2(GoodSpider):
    def parse(self, response: Response, *, a: str) -> None: ...  # Error
```

Comment: They don't have control of the `Spider` class IIUC

Comment: Oh well, I guess the scrapy developers have to support the correct typing API then :(

Comment: I *am* the Scrapy developer and I'm asking how to do this in `Spider`. For the tools, we are using mypy.

Comment: @wRAR pardon my ignorance! And the reason why I mentioned the type-checker used is that I only know mypy well (and by extension, pyright, as it tries to match mypy’s behaviour). The other two major type checkers (pyre and pytype) have behaviours and release cycles I’m not familiar with, and for your downstream users I’m not sure how well this last-argument-ellipsis will be received if they use these type checkers (or even older versions of pyright and mypy).

Comment: @dROOOze can you suggest why this still works on master but doesn't work in the recently released 1.6.0?

Comment: @wRAR I haven't tested this specifically, but my gut feeling is because [this PR didn't make it into the release](https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/15913). Since mypy has [public release plannings](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/15919), you should express your interest in this PR in their next one.